# Find Minimum + Maximum of function with constraints

Tags: optimization, lagrange-multiplier, maxima-minima, quadratic-programming, qcqp

homework assignment ask to find Max/Min for $$U(x,y,z) = x^2 + 2y^2 + 3z^2$$
with these constraints:

1. $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 1$
2. $x + 2y + 3z = 0$

Thank you.

First i tried to isolate x from the second constraint and then to put it in the first one .

Comment: Judging by the tags, you are aware of Lagrange multipliers. How would you use them in this case? Did you try something?

Comment: hi,
first i tried to isolate x from the second constraint and then to put it in the first one , then tried to use lagarange multipliers but stucked with really ugly equations so i thought there is might be more elegant way of doing it.

Comment: $$1=x^2+y^2+z^2=(2y+3z)^2+y^2+z^2=5y^2+10z^2+12yz=10\left(z+\dfrac35y\right)^2+y^2\left(5-\dfrac{18}5\right)$$

WLOG $\sqrt{10}\left(z+\dfrac35y\right)=\cos t,\sqrt{\dfrac75}y=\sin t$

$$x^2+2y^2+3z^2=1+y^2+2z^2=?$$

Comment: The traditional approach is to take the constraint functions $g_i(x)$, multiply them by $\lambda_i$ and then add to the function that you're trying to maximise/minimise. Did you try that?

Comment: yes, i tried that but ended up with a ''messy'' equations.

Comment: Elimination a variable is apparently not a point with this exercise, it is supposed to use Lagrange multipliers in a pretty straightforward manner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The goal is to find the min and max values of
$$f=x^2+2y^2+3z^2$$
subject to the constraints
$$
\begin{cases}
x^2+y^2+z^2=1&\;\;\;(\text{eq}1)\\[4pt]
x+2y+3z=0&\;\;\;(\text{eq}2)\\
\end{cases}
$$
Letting
\begin{align*}
g&=x^2+y^2+z^2-1\\[4pt]
h&=x+2y+3z\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
and using the method of Lagrange multipliers, it follows that the critical points $(x,y,z)$ satisfy the vector equation
$$\nabla{f} = a(\nabla{g})+b(\nabla{h})$$
for some $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$.

The associated scalar equations are
\begin{align*}
&2x = 2ax+b&&(\text{eq}3)\\[4pt]
&4y = 2ay+2b&&(\text{eq}4)\\[4pt]
&6z = 2az+3b&&(\text{eq}5)\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
With the above $3$ equations, together with $(\text{eq}1)$ and  $(\text{eq}2)$, we have a system of $5$ equations in $5$ unknowns.

If two of $x,y,z$ are zero, then by $(\text{eq}2)$, all three of $x,y,z$ sould be zero, but that would contradict $(\text{eq}1)$. Hence no two of $x,y,z$ are zero.

Next we show $a\not\in\{1,2,3\}$.

- If $a=1$, then $(\text{eq}3)$ would yield $b=0$, but then from $(\text{eq}4)$ and $(\text{eq}5)$, we would get $y=0$ and $z=0$, contradiction.$\\[4pt]$

  If $a=2$, then $(\text{eq}4)$ would yield $b=0$, but then from $(\text{eq}3)$ and $(\text{eq}5)$, we would get $x=0$ and $z=0$, contradiction.$\\[4pt]$

  If $a=3$, then $(\text{eq}5)$ would yield $b=0$, but then from $(\text{eq}3)$ and $(\text{eq}4)$, we would get $x=0$ and $y=0$, contradiction.

Hence $a\not\in\{1,2,3\}$, as claimed.

If $b=0$, then since $a\not\in\{1,2,3\}$, $(\text{eq}3)$ would yield $x=0$, $(\text{eq}4)$ would yield $y=0$, and $(\text{eq}5)$ would yield $z=0$, contradiction. Hence $b\ne 0$.

Solving $(\text{eq}3)$ for $x$, $(\text{eq}4)$ for $y$ and $(\text{eq}5)$ for $z$, we get
\begin{cases}
x={\Large{\frac{b}{2(1-a)}}}\\[4pt]
y={\Large{\frac{b}{2-a}}}\\[4pt]
z={\Large{\frac{3b}{2(3-a)}}}\\
\end{cases}
Replacing $x,y,z$ in $(\text{eq}2)$, we get
$$\frac{b(7a^2-24a+18)}{(1-a)(2-a)(3-a)}=0$$
hence
$$7a^2-24a+18=0$$
which solves as
$$
a={\small{\frac{3}{7}}}(4+s)
$$
where $s^2=2$ (i.e., $s=\pm\sqrt{2}$).

Replacing $a$ in $x^2,y^2,z^2$, and then rationalizing denominators, we get
\begin{cases}
x^2={\large{\frac{1}{4}}}b^2(43-30s)\\[4pt]
y^2={\large{\frac{1}{2}}}b^2(11+6s)\\[4pt]
z^2={\large{\frac{1}{4}}}b^2(11+6s)\\
\end{cases}
Replacing $x^2,y^2,z^2$ in $(\text{eq}2)$, and then solving for $b^2$, we get
$$
b^2={\small{\frac{1}{343}}}(19+3s)
$$
Replacing $b^2$ in $x^2,y^2,z^2$, and then rationalizing denominators, we get
\begin{cases}
x^2={\large{\frac{1}{28}}}(13-9s)\\[4pt]
y^2={\large{\frac{1}{14}}}(5+3s)\\[4pt]
z^2={\large{\frac{1}{28}}}(5+3s)\\
\end{cases}
Finally, replacing $x^2,y^2,z^2$ in $f$, we get
$$f={\small{\frac{3}{7}}}(4+s)={\small{\frac{3}{7}}}(4\pm\sqrt{2})$$
It follows that the maximum value of $f$ subject to the given constraints is
$${\small{\frac{3}{7}}}(4+\sqrt{2})\approx 2.320377241$$
and the minimum value of $f$ subject to the given constraints is
$${\small{\frac{3}{7}}}(4-\sqrt{2})\approx 1.108194187$$

Comment: Thank you for the whole explanation!

Comment: @Eyal Klemm: You're welcome! But I agree with your initial assessment -- solving the system is cumbersome.

Comment: @Eyal Klemm: Is it an exercise from a book? If so, which one?

Comment: I dont know if its from a book . We got it from previous semester exam for practicing.

Comment: @Eyal Klemm: What textbook are you using for the course?